# Split XML file into multiple files

Tags: bash, scripting, conversion, xml

I have an xml file that have different nodes, I want to split files like this:

```
<unix>
 <mm>
</unix>
<osx>
 <nn>
</osx>
```

When I run the script I want it to make one xml file called `unix.xml`,
which contains this

```
<unix
 <mm>
</unix>
```

And then another xml file called `osx.xml`, 
which contains this

```
<osx>
 <nn>
</osx>
```

Comment: This is no valid XML. An XML file has one root tag.

Answer (score 3):

First off - I'll say I think it's quite a bad idea to do XML parsing with anything other than an XML parser. Regular expressions may *look* like they're going to work, but this is a really good way to make some brittle code - XML that's semantically equivalent can look different to different REs (such as indents/linefeeds and unary tags).

So with that in mind - I would use Perl and the `XML::Twig` library. This is a pretty standard thing - there are prebuilt packages ubiquitously available.

However perhaps most importantly of all - the XML you have posted is NOT valid. I'm going to assume that's because it's a sample, and not the real XML, and so you've missed a bit off. I'm using as my sample:

```
<root>
<unix>
 <mm />
</unix>
<osx>
 <nn />
</osx>
</root>
```

And using this code will do what you ask for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' );
$twig->parsefile("your_xml.xml");

foreach my $element ( $twig->root->children ) {
    my $tag = $element->tag;
    print "Processing $tag\n";

    #print to STDOUT for debugging
    print $element ->sprint;

    #print to output file
    open( my $output, ">", "$tag.xml" ) or warn $!;
    print {$output} $element->sprint;
    close($output);
}
```

If of course, your posting of XML is *literally* what you have, then it is broken XML and you should ideally go and hit whoever gave you it a with a rolled up copy of the spec document. If that is impractical due to it being real life, then I would offer you this answer on Stack Overflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913945/2566198

Answer (score 0):

I think the follow should help. This is usual task which should to do between two limits.

```
unset f t
while read l
do
  t=${t:+$t\\n}$l
  l=${l//[<>]/}
  : ${f:="$l"}
  if [ "$l" = "/$f" ]
  then
    echo -e "$t" > "$f".xml 
    unset f t
  fi
done < <(cat your_xml_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[xml-cut](http://xml-coreutils.sourceforge.net/xml-cut_man.html)** from [xml-coreutils](http://xml-coreutils.sourceforge.net/) may accomplish your needs